# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) -->posed after I've checked all similar questions here

Tags: php, syntax

It is the function deserialiser that has problems. I checked semicolons and braces in this function.
I also checked the questions posed and their answers but none seemed helped.
thank you for helping me with this.

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /usercode/file.php on line 55

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Forum  ASI</title>
<meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link  href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   />
</head>
<body>
<header  id="top">
<h1>Forum  ASI</h1>  
</header>
<p id="probleme"></p>
<form  name="formulaire" action="post_message.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<fieldset>
<legend>Coordonnées :</legend>
<label  for="name">Nom : </label><input  placeholder="Saisissez  votre  nom"   id="name" name="name" type="text" size= "30" />
<label  for="email">E-mail : </label><input  placeholder="Saisissez  votre  email" id="email" name="email" type="text" size= "30" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Message :</legend>
<textarea  rows= "4"  cols= "50" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
</fieldset>
<input  type="submit" value="Poster  le  message" />
<input  type="reset" value="Effacer" />
</form>

<?php

class Message {
  private $date;
  private $nom;
  private $email;
  private $mess;

  public function __construct($nom, $email, $mess){
    $this-­>date = date('m/d/Y h­-i-­s a', time());
    $this-­>nom = $nom;
    $this­->email = $email;
    $this-­>mess = $mess;
  }

  public function serializer($nomFic){
    $fichier = fopen($nomFic, "a+");
    fputs($fichier,$this-­>date.": ".$this-­>nom.": ".$this-­>email.": ".$this-­>mess."\n");
    fclose($fichier);
  }
}

function deserialiser($nomFic){
  $fichier = fopen($nomFic, "r+");
  while(!feof($fichier)){
    $ligne = fgets($fichier);
    if(!empty($ligne)) {
      $tab = explode(':', $ligne,4); ​
      echo "<fieldset class='contour'><legend class='leg'>".$tab[0]." ".$tab[1]." ".$tab[2]."</legend><p>".$tab[3]."</p></fieldset>";  ​
    }
  }
  fclose($fichier);
}

?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){
  $message1=new Message($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['message'] );
  $message1-­>serializer("messages.txt");
  deserialiser("messages.txt");
}
?>


<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have some invisible characters in your code. Check it with a hex editor to see them. See the general answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18050072/3933332 under *"Invisible stray unicode characters"*

Comment: it works！！！！thank you very much!! a few backspaces after that line helped.